# Angular 9 throw error 'missing required parameter' on requesting token from Azure B2C

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, azure-ad-b2c, angular9, .net-core-3.1

I am working on Angular 9 application with .NET CORE Web API 3.1 application. I configure Angular client App to authenticate using Auth 2.0 Azure B2C and angular-oauth2-oidc in Angular. I am getting error on requesting token and CORS Policy in Browser. Screen shot at the end

```
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"AADB2C90083: The request is missing required parameter: grant_type.\r\nCorrelation ID: xxxx5370-695b-4f09-b583-e67600000000\r\nTimestamp: 2020-05-07 15:23:06Z\r\n"}
```

[image]

I configure postman and it successfully redirect to Microsoft login screen and return token. I have create Secret and grant permission client application to use Web API application in Azure under API Permission Section

### Component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { OAuthService, JwksValidationHandler } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc';
import { authConfig } from './auth.config';
import { JwksValidationHandler } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc-jwks';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
   })
 export class AppComponent {  
   title = 'Angular9B2CAuthApp';

 constructor(private oauthService:OAuthService){
    this.configureSingleSignOn();
  }

 configureSingleSignOn(){
   this.oauthService.configure(authConfig);
   this.oauthService.tokenValidationHandler = new JwksValidationHandler();
   this.oauthService.loadDiscoveryDocumentAndTryLogin();
}

 login(){
    this.oauthService.initImplicitFlow();
 }

 logout(){
   this.oauthService.logOut();
 }
}
```

### Auth.cofig

[image]

Not really sure what I am missing from puzzle. I have just realize one thing in Azure, i cannot run user flow of signin and out policy

[image]

Please refer to redirect URIs... I believe there is something missing?

[image]

I have found another issue, I am not sure if it inter link of what I am trying to solve it

[image]

[image]

Comment: In "Run User Flow",  should not select "AppCoreWebAPI" in the "Application" drop-down box, but "MyAngularClientApp"

Comment: Thanks Carl but my original problem remains there... have you got any idea why and how to solve it?

Comment: Can you show the 'get' request of the first screenshot completely?

Comment: I get error soon I call http//localhost:4200 ... Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://mytanent.b2clogin.com/xxxx2f8c-5ff5-4e69-b831-b6xxxxxxxxxx/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 

Please refer to second last for full screenshot

Comment: This is not what I want. Could you pls provide the full content of the request in the first screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1plSA.png?

Comment: I have updated first screen shot, please refer above

Comment: I have also uploaded auth.config.ts file above...

Comment: You try to enter your request parameters according to this document? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/implicit-flow-single-page-application